# Javascript QUnit test failing when output is correct

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net-mvc, qunit

I am just learning QUnit and am using a tutorial off the net. [Unit Testing Javascript in ASP NET MVC](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/pranab/2013/06/20/unit-testing-javascriptjquery-in-asp-net-mvc-project-using-qunit-step-by-step/)

I have used the following code, but the test fails regardless of the fact that I know that the test data equals the correct number.

The cshtml file:

```
@{Html.EnableUnobtrusiveJavaScript(true);}


@section Scripts {
<script type="text/javascript">
    var cityCount = 0;
    $(document).ready(function () {
        getCountry();
        $('#CountriesID').change(function () {
            getCity('AU');
        });
    });
    function getCountry() {
        var url = '@Url.Content("~/Home/CountryList")/';

        $.getJSON(url, function (data) {
            var items = [];
            items.push("<option>Select a Country</option>");
            $.each(data, function (i, country) {
                if (country.Value.indexOf("\'") > -1) {
                    s = country.Value + " " + country.Text;
                    alert(s + ": Country.Value cannot contain \'")
                }
                items.push("<option value='" + country.Value + "'>" + country.Text + "</option>");
            });
            $('#CountriesID').html(items.join());
        })
    }

    function getCity(countryId) {
        var url = '@Url.Content("~/Home/CityList")/' + countryId;

        $.getJSON(url, function (data) {
            var items = [];
            var cityCount = 0;
            items.push('<option>Select a City</option>');
            $.each(data, function (i, city) {
                items.push("<option value='" + city.Value + "'>" + city.Text + "</option>");
                cityCount++;
            });
            alert(cityCount);
            $('#CitiesID').html(items.join());
        });
    }

    test("Perform Country onchange", function () {
        $('#CountriesID').trigger("change");
        equals(cityCount, 3, 'The no. of cities should be 3');
    });

</script> 
}
<h2>Country</h2>
@Html.ActionLink("Home", "Index", "Home")

<div class="container">
    <div id="CountriesDivID">
        <label for="Countries">Countries</label>
        <select id="CountriesID" name="Countries"></select>
    </div>    
    <div id="CitiesDivID" >
        <label for="Cities">Cities</label>
        <select id="CitiesID" name="Cities"></select>
    </div>
</div>
<div class="tests">
    <h1 id="qunit-header">QUnit example</h1>               
    <ol id="qunit-tests"></ol>
</div>
```

I have an alert in the GetCity method to alert me of the value of cityCount which is what is being tested against. It is assert that it should equal 3.

[image]

Yet, this is the result of the tests.

[image]

So, my question is, what am I doing wrong?

Edit: If I strip out the contents of GetCity and just set citCount = 3, the test passes.

Comment: Your code in `async` -- the Ajax triggered by the change hasn't finished before you are testing for the answer.  Your `alert` happens within the ajax callback and, thus, does see the right answer.  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14220321/how-do-i-return-the-response-from-an-asynchronous-call